# How to convert python gtk pixbuf to simplecv image

Tags: python, image, gtk, simplecv

I'm using simplecv to extract features from images. I use gtk to take a screenshot in python.

```
import gtk.gdk as g
w = g.get_default_root_window()
sz = [400,300]
pb = g.Pixbuf(g.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8,*sz)
cm = w.get_colormap()
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,cm,0,0,0,0,*sz)
```

How do I then convert that screenshot pixbuf to a SimpleCV Image instance?

Comment: goto http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/opencv-with-pygtk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some experimenting, given you have a pixbuf of an image named pb, then you can create a SimpleCV Image from pb like so

```
im = Image(pb.get_pixels_array())
```